# Adding an XML Node with a namespace to an existing document using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, rss

How do I add an xml node with a namespace prefix to an existing document?  I would like to build off of what I have so far, if possible:

```
def rss = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)

rss.channel + {
item {
    title("My super atom feed")
    link(href:"http://www.thecoderscorner.com")
    description("content of rss item goes here")
    guid(isPermaLink: "false", "8452")  
}
}
```

I want to add the following to the item above:

```
<event:startDate>Tue, 8 Apr 2014 15:00:00 PDT</event:startDate>
<event:endDate>Tue, 8 Apr 2014 18:00:00 PDT</event:endDate>
<event:location>1234 Mrak Hall</event:location>
<event:isAllDay>false</event:isAllDay>
```

Comment: Can You please provide a full functional example, with declared namespaces etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
def rss = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )
rss.channel.item + {
    item {
        title("My super atom feed")
        link(href:"http://www.thecoderscorner.com")
        description("content of rss item goes here")
        guid(isPermaLink: "false", "8452")  
        'event:startDate'( "Tue, 8 Apr 2014 15:00:00 PDT" )
        'event:endDate'( "Tue, 8 Apr 2014 18:00:00 PDT" )
        'event:location'( "1234 Mrak Hall" )
        'event:isAllDay'( false )
    }
}
String output = new StringWriter().with { xmlOutput ->
    new XmlNodePrinter( new PrintWriter( xmlOutput ) ).with { printer ->
        preserveWhitespace = true
        expandEmptyElements = true
        printer.print( rss )
    }
    xmlOutput.toString()
}

println output
```